# Android Sat Nav Apps

Tags: applications, gps, external-gps

I have a few questions about Sat Nav applications running on Android.

1. Does the pre-installed sat nav app require a connection to the web? Does it operate in car and pedestrian modes and be updated automatically.
2. Am I right in thinking that the *after market purchase* of the Tom-Tom app can function without internet connection?

Thanks for any replies.

Answer (score 0):

Android provides different methods for localization. Some of them are network based, some cell based, some GPS based, some mixed (well, that was simplified).

So yes: You could use plain GPS without network. Might take a little longer to get your initial fix, though. ([Assisted GPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assisted_GPS) aka AGPS can speed this up, but requires a network connection.)

And quite logically yes to your second question as well, as far as GPS is concerned. For map data, if it's already downloaded to your device, no data connection is required either. But if you need updates while on the way, or want to be updated about traffic, things are certainly a little different.